# How to capture event and stop it from bubble up to parent in jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that displays a tree list using unordered lists.  For each li that has children, I want it to make an ajax call to go get those children and then display them as another ul/li combo.  That works.
But then, if one of the children is also a parent, I want it to again make an ajax call and go get it's children.

The issue is that when I make the additional call, it makes that call, but then additionally calls the parent and removes the previous call.

This is the issue:

```
 -Parent
  - Child 1
  - Child 2 
    - child a <-- clicking here briefly opens up kids.  Then "getchildren" 
      - child 2.a  \-- bubbles up to Child 2. Then displays only child 
      - child 2.b   \- a, b, c and child 2.a and 2.b go away.
    - child b
    - child c
  - Child 3
```

Here is the actual jquery function that makes the Ajax call:

```
function getChildren(tsk) { 
    var taskId = '#'.concat(tsk);
    alert("getChildren::taskid = "+taskId);

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "kids1.jsp?taskId="+tsk,
        success: function(data){
            alert("getChildren.ajax::data="+data);
            $(taskId).html(data);
        }
    });
    event.stopPropagation();  // <-- this doesn't work
}
```

This is the "view source" version of my page (once it's rendered).  This shows what the links look like that make the "getChildren(tsk)" call.  The code that creates the li entries is shown below this.
This is the TOP (parent) level.

```
<ul class="mktree" id="tree1">
<li class="liOpen" id="theJob" style="visibility:hidden">
    <a href="jobDetail.jsp?rowSelected=1&jobNameSelected=2017_sb207_HRS89E-1_RP-HI.EDEN_PDU.09-06.09:39:09.tpcz4686-001" onClick='boldTask(this)' id="black" target=right>2017_sb207_HRS89E-1_RP-HI.EDEN_PDU.09-06.09:39:09.tpcz4686-001</a></li>
<ul id="treeList" name="treeList" style="visibility:hidden">

            <li id=0200001700CE36AC143D0002000073B1><a href='taskDetail.jsp?taskNameSelected=0200001700CE36AC143D0002000073B1' id='gray'  onClick='boldTask(this)' target=right>&nbsp;Batcher</a><input type='hidden' name='Batcher' value='com.lxnx.fab.wim.nfdjobmon.util.TaskInfo@91a0c3'></li> 

            <li class='liClosed' id=0200001700CE36AC14F60002000073B1 onClick=getChildren('0200001700CE36AC14F60002000073B1')><a href='taskDetail.jsp?taskNameSelected=0200001700CE36AC14F60002000073B1' id='blue'  target=right>&nbsp;SEARCH_LOCK_ACT</a><input type='hidden' name='SEARCH_LOCK_ACT' value='com.lxnx.fab.wim.nfdjobmon.util.TaskInfo@17f6796'></li> 

            <li id=0200001700CE36AC14B00002000073B1><img src='images/done.gif'><a href='taskDetail.jsp?taskNameSelected=0200001700CE36AC14B00002000073B1' id='blue'  onClick='boldTask(this)' target=right>&nbsp;BinderCreator</a><input type='hidden' name='BinderCreator' value='com.lxnx.fab.wim.nfdjobmon.util.TaskInfo@169bc15'></li> 
...
```

Here is the code that includes the getChildren call.  It calls a java method (getChildTasks3) that creates the individual li entries.

```
<ul class="mktree" id="theJob" style="visibility:hidden">
    <a href="jobDetail.jsp?rowSelected=<%=rowSelected%>&jobNameSelected=<%=jobNameSelected%>" onClick='boldTask(this)' id="black" target=right><%=jobNameSelected%></a>
<%
    // At this point, we've got the job
    // Now get all the tasks
    long Ltime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ArrayList jobTasks = job.getOrderedTasks();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < jobTasks.size(); i++) {

        TaskInfo jobTask = (TaskInfo)jobTasks.get(i);
        request.setAttribute("taskNameSelected",jobTask.getTaskId());
        tmpSession.setAttribute(jobTask.getTaskId(),jobTask);

        String taskOutput = jobTask.getChildTasks3(jobTask, tmpSession);
        %>
        <%=taskOutput%>
        <%
    }

%>
</ul>
```

First - how can I capture the event in my function getChildren(tsk) ? Do I need to capture it?  How can I get it to only run for the entry I click on -- and not the parent entry?

I'm a newbie to jquery - so I appreciate any and all help!!

UPDATE: I was able to get it working using the onClick function.  I tried using the class=myClickable and it's now ONLY calling the parent.  Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".my-clickable").on('click', function(event) {
        var taskId=$(this).attr('id');
        var tsk = '#'.concat(taskId);

        alert("in clickable function: id: "+taskId);  // <-- parent ID
        //event.stopPropagation();

        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request 
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "kids1.jsp?taskId="+taskId,
            success: function(data){
                alert("clickable.ajax::data="+data);
                //$(tsk).html(data);
                $(tsk).append(data);
            }
        });  // end ajax
        event.cancelBubble=true;
     });

});
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is that you should do the following in your inline onclick handler:

`onClick=getChildren(event, '0200001700CE36AC14F60002000073B1')`

and then change your `getChildren` function to:

```
function getChildren(event, tsk) { 
    var taskId = '#'.concat(tsk);
    alert("getChildren::taskid = "+taskId);

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "kids1.jsp?taskId="+tsk,
        success: function(data){
            alert("getChildren.ajax::data="+data);
            $(taskId).html(data);
        }
    });
    event.stopPropagation();  // <-- this should now work
}
```

The longer answer is that you should avoid binding click handlers inline, and rather bind them using javascript, a quick reference to get you started on that: [JavaScript ‘this’ and Event Handlers](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/)

[Edit]
Here is a snippet you can run that shows the quick answer way, as well as the preferred way:

```js
function myFunction(event, id) {
  console.log(id);
  event.stopPropagation(); 
}

// prefered way of doing click events (or any other event binding)
$(function() {
 $(".my-clickable").on('click', function(event) {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  event.stopPropagation(); 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li onclick="myFunction(event, 'A')">Parent A
    <ul>
      <li onclick="myFunction(event, 'A.1')">Child A.1</li>
      <li onclick="myFunction(event, 'A.2')">Child A.2</li>
      <li onclick="myFunction(event, 'A.3')">Child A.3</li>
      <li onclick="myFunction(event, 'A.4')">Child A.4</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
  <li id="B" class="my-clickable">Parent B
    <ul>
      <li id='B.1' class="my-clickable">Child B.1</li>
      <li id='B.2' class="my-clickable">Child B.2</li>
      <li id='B.3' class="my-clickable">Child B.3</li>
      <li id='B.4' class="my-clickable">Child B.4</li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
  <li>Parent C</li>
  <li>Parent D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried that and it's still not working.  Should I be using "onClick=getChildren(event, '0200...)" with nothing special around event?  Do I need to put event in single quotes or something?

Comment: Ok - this is life changing!! I see the benefit to using the class vs the onClick event.  I'm using the class version now.  One additional question - is it possible to make my ajax call w/in the my-clickable function ?     THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: I see that it is possible to make the ajax call.  I just have to get the tree configured correctly.  Thank you again! :)

Comment: Sorry for the churn - but I'm now facing another issue.  When I changed this to use the "preferred way" - my li parent is now always being passed as the "this" when I click on any of the children.  each child has it's own ID value set.  I don't understand why it's sending the parent value on the click event.

Comment: If you can post me a jsfiddle to look at, then I can look into it for you

Comment: I'm not sure what a jfiddle is.  sorry :)  I was able to get this to work using my original method (onClick=myfunction()...).  but I really wanted to use the class version.  unfortunately, every time I would click on a child li element - it would trigger the parent.  The parent ID was being passed as the ID.  I'm using jquery-1.11.3.js if that makes a difference.